# Persist/retrieve evaluation results in FiftyOne

Tags: python, object-detection

I am using the amazing [FiftyOne](https://voxel51.com/fiftyone) to analyze machine learning model evaluations.

I have an existing (persistent) dataset.  In a previous session, I ran an evaluation on it:

```
python
>>> import fiftyone as fo
>>> dataset = fo.load_dataset("existing_dataset")
>>> dataset.list_evaluations()
[eval]
```

I would like to retrieve the `results` object associated with this evaluation without running the `dataset.evaluate_detections` method.

We have multiple teams are will analyze these results, and we need to ensure that all teams have the same data/values.  It also would be convenient to access results without waiting for them to be generated.

**What I Tried**

1. The command `dataset.get_evaluation_info("eval")` returns high level information about the evaluation, but not the results themselves.
2. When I generated the results, doing a `pickle` on the `results` object gives a `PicklingError` associated with the `mongoengine.base.metaclasses`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you like the tool!

What you're looking for is the [`dataset.load_evaluation_results("eval")`](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/api/fiftyone.core.collections.html#fiftyone.core.collections.SampleCollection.load_evaluation_results) method.
It will return the results object even after persisting and reloading a dataset.

[`get_evaluation_info()`](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/api/fiftyone.core.collections.html#fiftyone.core.collections.SampleCollection.get_evaluation_info) is used to access the info and arguments used to create the evaluation. Also just FYI, [`load_evaluation_view()`](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/api/fiftyone.core.collections.html#fiftyone.core.collections.SampleCollection.load_evaluation_view) can be used to load the exact [View](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/using_views.html) that was evaluated.

Accessing results while they are being generated could be quite useful. Please feel free to create a feature request on GitHub: https://github.com/voxel51/fiftyone/issues